# NuGet packages missing on gitlab.com package repository

Tags: .net, gitlab, nuget

Trying to push a package to a nuget source on gitlab. I get

```
  PUT https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/xxx/packages/nuget/
  Created https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/xxx/packages/nuget/ 1325ms
Your package was pushed.
```

and intercepting the call, gitlab's nuget server returns `{201 Created}`.

However the package is actually not there when I query the server.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your nuget package `version` metadata to be with 3 numbers only instead of 4 i.e. `x.x.x` instead of `x.x.x.x`

Gitlab's nuget server accepts nuget packages with only 3 version parts, and silently fails on 4.

Comment: Yes, I also had packages with 2 digit versions and they don't upload either.